# Formatted string from JodaTime duration

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to get formatted string from JodaTime's duration class.

```
Duration duration = new Duration(durationInSecond * 1000);
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                .appendDays()
                .appendSuffix(" days, ")
                .appendHours()
                .appendSuffix(" hours, ")
                .appendMinutes()
                .appendSuffix(" minutes and ")
                .appendSeconds()
                .appendSuffix(" seconds")
                .toFormatter();
String formattedString = formatter.print(duration.toPeriod());
```

Value of `formattedString` should be

> 65 days, 3 hours, 5 minutes and 20 seconds

But It is

> 1563 hours, 5 minutes, 20 seconds

1563 hours are 65 days and 3 hours but formatter is not printing in that manner.

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a `PeriodType` along with [Period.normalizedStandard(org.joda.time.PeriodType)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#normalizedStandard(org.joda.time.PeriodType)) to specify which fields you are interested in.

In your case `PeriodType.dayTime()`seems appropriate .

```
Duration duration = new Duration(durationInSecond * 1000);
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendDays()
        .appendSuffix(" days, ")
        .appendHours()
        .appendSuffix(" hours, ")
        .appendMinutes()
        .appendSuffix(" minutes, ")
        .appendSeconds()
        .appendSuffix(" seconds")
        .toFormatter();

Period period = duration.toPeriod();
Period dayTimePeriod = period.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.dayTime());
String formattedString = formatter.print(dayTimePeriod);

System.out.println(formattedString);
```

Answer (score 3):

I found using [`PeriodFormat.getDefault()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormat.html#getDefault()) helpful for creating the PeriodFormatter, without having to do all the extra work using the PeriodFormatterBuilder and creating your own. It gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

`PeriodFormat.wordBased` is same as `PeriodFormat.getDefault()` but accept `Locale` param.

```kotlin
import java.util.Locale
import org.joda.time.Duration
import org.joda.time.PeriodType
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormat


PeriodFormat.wordBased(
    Locale("en"))
    .print(
        Duration(1653419081151L)
            .toPeriod()
            .normalizedStandard(
//                PeriodType.standard() // 2733 weeks, 5 days, 19 hours, 4 minutes, 41 seconds and 151 milliseconds
//                PeriodType.dayTime() // 19136 days, 19 hours, 4 minutes, 41 seconds and 151 milliseconds
//                PeriodType.weeks() // 2733 weeks
                PeriodType.days() // 19136 days
            )
    )
```

will give you proper output in the preferred language.

Or use own `PeriodType`:

```
normalizedStandard(
            PeriodType.forFields(
                arrayOf(
                    DurationFieldType.years(),
                    DurationFieldType.months(),
                    DurationFieldType.days(),
                    DurationFieldType.hours(),
                    DurationFieldType.minutes()
                )
            )
```